# Azure Pipeline Angular Build Docker Image fails

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I'm new to Azure and having multiple problems. I would like to log how the data structure or the content of the build looks like to learn what the problem is.

I tried several attempts to build a Docker image out of the build artifacts but always get this message in the Docker build task:

```
##[error]COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat dist: file does not exist
```

I guess it is possible to use the existing artifacts to not build them again in the Dockerfile like usually:

```
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js 12.x'
- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
  displayName: 'Build Docker IMAGE'
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'dist'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
  displayName: 'Archive files'
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    artifact: 'Angular'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
  displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'specific'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

I mean why does it not work. When I delete the Docker task it works like a charm. And there is the option `rootFolderOrFile: 'dist'` used.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

I also tried different folders like `dist/Angular_Project_Name`.

Comment: You're not specifying a working directory for any of this. Look at the folder structure and ensure you're running your `docker` command in the appropriate directory. However, I'd suggest that what you should *really* be doing is building your code *in the container* rather than building it externally and then copying it in.

Comment: I didn't even know that there is something like a working directory sadly. Why should I build it in the container? What's the advantage? It's like I did it before without Azure but I just thought it's doubled runtime for nothing because I build the artifacts and the Docker image with the same artifacts. @DanielMann

Comment: There's no reason to build the artifacts on the agent. You just build it once, in the container. Then your pipeline agent doesn't need additional tooling like node installed.